# "Take the tour" message about how to obtain first badge doesn't make sense on child metas

Tags: bug, profile-page, informed-badge, per-site-meta

On child meta sites, new users (those who don't have a badge yet) see the message "Take the Tour and earn your first badge" in their profile page. The message is the same as on the normal Q&A sites.

[image: Take the Tour and earn your first badge]

However, on meta pages, the tour is linked to their parent site and it's not possible to obtain the informed badge on sub meta sites, so the message is useless on meta. For my user, I saw this message on http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com and http://meta.superuser.com/

Comment: I agree with your observations, but Meta is tied closely with the main site, so I think a slight change of wording would resolve this. Then we don't miss out on an opportunity to entice users to view the Tour as it might help some understand the Stack Exchange format better. Something like "Take the tour on the main site" (etc).

Comment: I think that the button is close enough in the help menu on the top of each page. And normally users who are on a meta page already visited their parent site. But I agree that it's a minor bug :-)

Comment: "*normally users who are on a meta page already visited their parent site*" That is quite likely, yes, but that doesn't mean they've viewed the Tour. Giving them a more prominent visual nudge might get them to read the Tour page, which is the entire point of the badge. New users can be bewildered with all the links and buttons going on, and it might be a little while before they use that "Help" dropdown.. Regardless of our (friendly) debate, I don't see any harm in having the notification, just needs rewording. Is there a reason (other than the wording) you want to get rid of it?

Comment: @James I think the link is in an area which informs about badges, and 'Informed' is not a badge you can get. In fact, if this information wasn't there, I would be able to track the progress of my Enthusiast badge (quite useless, I know, but the descendant of the ape sometimes needs some primitive motivation :-P ). So, you see, it's not too important for me how it is solved. It's just something which confused me when I saw it the first time.

Comment: "*Informed is not a badge you can get*" You mean in meta specifically? If so, again rewording would resolve that. If people are going to Meta for help, then I like the idea of them being prompted to visit the Tour page, even if it states "Take the Tour on the main site".

Comment: Yes, that would be enough (without the "and earn your first badge") (and yes, I mean in meta; the text on the main page is ok)